# Missing Artifacts - Version not supporting for Websphere Mq 7.0

Tags: java, spring, ibm-mq

I am novice in Websphere Mq. I am trying to build a connection using Spring Jms. For learning purpose, I am trying some examples.

Pom.xml
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.java.geek</groupId>
<artifactId>sample-spring-was-jms</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>sample-spring-was-jms</name> 
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <version.spring>3.0.5.RELEASE</version.spring>
    <version.was>7.0.1.3</version.was>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.websphere</groupId>
        <artifactId>runtime</artifactId>
        <version>${version.was}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
        <artifactId>mq</artifactId>
        <version>${version.was}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
        <artifactId>mqjms</artifactId>
        <version>${version.was}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
        <artifactId>dhbcore</artifactId>
        <version>${version.was}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.ws.webservices</groupId>
        <artifactId>thinclient</artifactId>
        <version>${version.was}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.14</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
        <artifactId>geronimo-jms_1.1_spec</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${version.spring}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${version.spring}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
        <version>${version.spring}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.sibc</groupId>
        <artifactId>sibc.jms</artifactId>
        <version>6.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.sibc</groupId>
        <artifactId>sibc.jndi</artifactId>
        <version>6.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.sibc</groupId>
        <artifactId>sibc.orb</artifactId>
        <version>6.1</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

I am getting an error, "Missing artifact" wherever I have used  ${version.was}. Anyone have any idea which version does it support? Or am I doing any other mistake. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

5.3.07 version supports for mq and mqjms.

For dhbcore, if Websphere Mq is installed on your system then you can get the file from their.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm</groupId>
            <artifactId>dhbcore</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.07</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/dhbcore.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
```